# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in RoastsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is a new error to me, and struggling to resolve it. It also states: `Roaster(#70130698993440) expected, got "1" which is an instance of String(#70130675908140)`

It's highlighting my create method in my Roasts Controller:

```
  def create
    @roast = Roast.new(roast_params)
```

The scenario is that I'm trying to create a triple nested form. for three models `Roasts` `Countries` and `Regions` where roasts has many countries and countries has many regions.

I'm assuming there is something wrong with the roast params, but I can see what it is.  I have added the associations there for the nested models

```
def roast_params
  params.require(:roast).permit(:roaster, :name, :bestfor, :beans, :roast, :tastingnotes, :notes, :slug, :avatar, :countries_attributes => [:country_name, :regions_attributes => [:region_name]])
end
```

**my form**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.fields_for :countries do |countries_form| %>
      <%= countries_form.label :country %>
      <%= countries_form.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>

  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.fields_for :regions do |regions_form| %>
        <%= regions_form.label :region %>
        <%= regions_form.text_field :region_name, class: "form-control" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

**Roast Controller**

```
...
  def new
    @roast = Roast.new
    @roast.countries.build.regions.build
  end
...
```

**roast model**

```
class Roast < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tastings
  has_many :countries
  has_many :notes, through: :tastings
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  belongs_to :roaster
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :countries
```

**country model**

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions, inverse_of: :country
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :regions
  belongs_to :roasts
```

**region model**

```
class Region < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
```

I've nested the regions params in the country params, is that correct?  I also saw on SO other issues with suggestions for setting `config.cache_classes` to `true` in `development.rb` but that didn't help here.

*Update*
So looking at this further, I believe it's not related to the nested forms, but rather a collection_select I'm using.

```
<%= form.label :roaster, class: 'control-label' %>
<%= form.collection_select(:roaster, Roaster.order(:roaster_name).all, :id, :roaster_name, prompt: true, class: "form-control") %>
```

So this select is pulling the `roaster_name` from a model called `Roaster`.

My params now look like the below:

```
  params.require(:roast).permit(:roaster_name, :roaster, :name, :bestfor, :beans, :roast, :tastingnotes, :notes, :slug, :avatar, :countries_attributes => [:country_id, :country_name, :regions_attributes => [:region_id, :region_name]])
```

And looking at the console when submitting the form, it seems that just the :id of Roaster is getting passed, rather than the value of :roaster_name.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"EG+zty85IiVsgipm1pjSAEZ7M66ELWefLq8Znux+cf89sSnVXxielRr1IaSS9+cJvdQD8g1D4+v2KqtKEwh6gw==",
 "roast"=>{"roaster"=>"1", "name"=>"Espress", "countries_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"country_name"=>"UK"}}, "regions"=>{"region_name"=>"Highlands"}, "bestfor"=>"", "roast"=>"", "tastingnotes"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Roast"}
```

Can't work this out

Comment: Why do you want the roaster_name? Assuming you want to assign an existing Roaster to a Roast, you should consider passing `roast_id` from the form into the Roast `create` action.

Comment: you have to send `roaster_id` in the roast params

Comment: can you paste your `collection_select ` which you are thinking to give error?

Comment: just added the collection sellect.

Answer (score 0):

[`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AssociationTypeMismatch.html) is raised when an association-setter (`Roast#roaster=` in this case) is called with a value that is not an instance of the expected class. `Roaster` was expected, got `String`.

The issue seems to be with passing `roaster` in as a param, which is "1" (String) in your example. I'm guessing this is actually an ID of a Roaster, the form code in the question does not show it.

Perhaps you meant to permit and pass a `roaster_id` param?

```
def roast_params
  params.require(:roast).permit(:roaster_id, # ... 
end
```

Comment: thanks messanjah.  I've just updated the post, as I think the problem might actually lie with a collection_select in the form.